# Position pgfplots two column environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, graphics, subfloats

I usually produce my plots through `pgfplots`. However, I have an alignment problem in the `twocolumn` environment. Indeed, if I produce only one graph it results correctly aligned to the column. When I do this in a `subfloat` environment the graphs are not aligned to the single graph. I would like to know if there is a way to align the plots in the subfloat environment to the single graphs.
Moreover, the size of the effective graph (without considering the labels) depends on the labels themselves (for example when the label contains an integral sign). Is there a way to fix the size of the "effective" graph?

Below and example for clarification

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{pgfplots}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}[!h]
\centering
\subfloat[graph A]
{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    width=0.36\textwidth,
    height=0.27\textwidth,
]

\addplot [
    domain=-10:10, 
    samples=100, 
    color=red,
]{x^2 - 2*x - 1};
\addlegendentry{\(x^2 - 2x - 1\)}


\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}}
%\hspace{3cm}
\subfloat[graph B]
{\label{fig:totalTemperatureAmp}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    width=0.36\textwidth,
    height=0.27\textwidth,
]

\addplot [
    domain=-10:10, 
    samples=100, 
    color=red,
]{x^2 - 2*x - 1};
\addlegendentry{\(x^2 - 2x - 1\)}


\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\caption{graph in subfloat enviroment}
\label{fig:amplitudeBC}
\end{figure*}


\begin{figure}[!t]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    width=0.36\textwidth,
    height=0.27\textwidth,
]

\addplot [
    domain=-10:10, 
    samples=100, 
    color=red,
]{x^2 - 2*x - 1};
\addlegendentry{\(x^2 - 2x - 1\)}


\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{graph in figure enviroment}
\label{fig:pm}
\end{figure}



\blindtext \blindtext \blindtext \blindtext \blindtext \blindtext \blindtext \blindtext \blindtext \blindtext \blindtext \blindtext \blindtext \blindtext \blindtext \blindtext


\end{document}
```

Comment: Try to nest the subfloats in a `strip` environment, from the `cuted` package (`stt` bundle).  It should appear at the top of the following page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using two `subfigure` environments, and set their width to `\columnwidth`, with an `\hfill` between them. Note I also used `\columnwidth` for the `axis` size.

Regarding your last question, are you perhaps after the `scale only axis` option? I.e., with `\begin{axis}[scale only axis, width=5cm]`, the 5cm determine the size of the axis box alone, without labels.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{pgfplots}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}[!h]
\begin{subfigure}{\columnwidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    width=0.8\columnwidth,
    height=0.6\columnwidth,
]

\addplot [
    domain=-10:10, 
    samples=100, 
    color=red,
]{x^2 - 2*x - 1};
\addlegendentry{\(x^2 - 2x - 1\)}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Graph A}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{\columnwidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    width=0.8\columnwidth,
    height=0.6\columnwidth,
]

\addplot [
    domain=-10:10, 
    samples=100, 
    color=red,
]{x^2 - 2*x - 1};
\addlegendentry{\(x^2 - 2x - 1\)}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{graph B}
\label{fig:totalTemperatureAmp}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{graph in subfloat enviroment}
\label{fig:amplitudeBC}
\end{figure*}


\begin{figure}[!t]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    width=0.8\columnwidth,
    height=0.6\columnwidth,
]

\addplot [
    domain=-10:10, 
    samples=100, 
    color=red,
]{x^2 - 2*x - 1};
\addlegendentry{\(x^2 - 2x - 1\)}


\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{graph in figure enviroment}
\label{fig:pm}
\end{figure}



\blindtext \blindtext \blindtext \blindtext \blindtext \blindtext \blindtext \blindtext \blindtext \blindtext \blindtext \blindtext \blindtext \blindtext \blindtext \blindtext


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the time you spent writing the solution. That's exactly what I wanted for both the problems.